# Python vs. Windows: File size calculator discrepancy

Tags: python, file, size, os.walk

I recently made a simple file size calculator using os.walk() in python as follows:

```
import os

totalSize = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("F:\\Japan"):
    for name in files:
        totalSize += os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in dirs:
        totalSize += os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, name))

print(totalSize)
```

When I execute this code the output is 7,731,584,492 bytes, but when I analyze the same directory with right click > properties the file size is 7,731,486,188 bytes. Now, I know that a discrepancy of 98,304 bytes isn't much, but I would like to know if there is either a problem with my code or a more fundamental reason to this discrepancy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following test on my own machine:

```
>>> os.path.getsize(r'F:\My Music\Audio')
98304
```

I would say that the Windows size calculation does not include the space taken up by the file that describes a directory itself, while your code explicitly does (with the second inner `for` loop). The file for the particular directory you are inspecting happens to have that size.